# Error al sacar promedio en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

```py
class Problema2:
    edades=[]


    def _asignar(self,listaEdades):
        self.edades=listaEdades
        
    def promedio(self):
        return sum(self.edades)/len(self.edades)
    
    def menor(self):

      return (min(self.edades))

    def mayor(self):
        print((max(self.edades)))

    def cantMenores(self):
        return len(self.edades>17)

    def cantMayores(self):
        len(self.edades<18)
    
    def mayorA(self):
        len(self.edades<57)
    
    def imprimir(self,mensaje):
        print(mensaje)


edades=[]
ObjProm=Problema2()

total_personas = int(input("[!] Ingrese la c antidad de personas: "))

for i in range(total_personas):
    edades.append(int(input(f"Introduzca la edad de la persona {i+1}: ")))

ObjProm.promedio()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    ObjProm.promedio()
  File "main.py", line 9, in promedio
    return sum(self.edades)/len(self.edades)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

Comment: ¿Qué error? Debes editar tu pregunta e incluir todos los detalles

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, te recomiendo leer o releer sobre clases en python, hay algunos errores de concepto y por eso no funciona ([documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/classes.html))

Si agregas un `print(self.edades)` en la definición de promedio vas a darte cuenta que devuelve una lista vacía, eso es porque nunca asignaste ningun valor a `self.edades`

```
def promedio(self):
    print(self.edades)
    return sum(self.edades)/len(self.edades)
```

Esto devuelve la lista vacía `[]` y el error diciendo que hay una división entre `0` ya que `len([])` es cero.

Esto es porque la variable `edades` fuera de la función y la variable `edades` dentro de la función no son la misma, `edades` dentro de la función tiene alcance local, únicamente adentro de la función y por lo tanto cuando asignas algunos valores desde tu `input` los asignas a `edades` que está fuera de la función

Podrías utilizar una variable global para que copie los valores a la variable local adentro de tu función, pero eso no sería muy buena práctica, lo ideal es que tengas un método de inicialización (La operación de instanciación **init** lo hace) ya que tu método `_asignar()` nunca se ejecuta.

En otras palabras, `__init__` siempre se ejecuta al crear una instancia de tu clase

Ejemplo:

```
class Problema2(object):
    def __init__(self, edades):
        self.edades = edades
        print(self.edades)

a=[10,20,30,60]
ObjProm=Problema2(a)
```

Al ejecutar el código anterior vas a darte cuenta que ahora sí `self.edades` obtiene los valores que recibe la instancia `ObjProm` de la clase `Problema2` al ser creada. Nota que `__init__(self, edades)` recibe un arguménto `edades`, al pasar la lista `a` al crear la instancia de la clase se inicializa `self.edades` con lo que contenga `a`

Otros problemas en tu clase son los métodos que calculan el número de elementos menores o mayores a cierta edad. No es posible hacer `len(self.edades < 17)`, tendrías que crear una nueva lista únicamente con los elementos que cumplan con la condición (Por cierto, creo que también tienes que repasar mayor que `>` y menor que `<` porque están al revés en tu código).

Para crear la nueva lista con las edades que cumplan cierta condición puedes hacerlo con un ciclo `for` o con [comprensión de listas](https://docs.hektorprofe.net/python/funcionalidades-avanzadas/comprension-de-listas/), esta segunda opción es la que voy a utilizar en la respuesta.

Algo que no menciona tu pregunta es si los métodos de tu clase deben retornar o imprimir los resultados

Ejemplo completo:

```
class Problema2(object):
    def __init__(self, edades):
        self.edades = edades
        
    def promedio(self):
        return sum(self.edades)/len(self.edades)
    
    def menor(self):
        return min(self.edades)

    def mayor(self):
        return max(self.edades)

    def cantMenores(self):
        return len([x for x in self.edades if x <= 17])

    def cantMayores(self):
        return len([x for x in self.edades if x >= 18])
    
    def mayorA(self):
        return len([x for x in self.edades if x >= 57])
    
    def imprimir(self,mensaje):
        print(mensaje)

edades=[]
total_personas = int(input("[!] Ingrese la c antidad de personas: "))
for i in range(total_personas):
    edades.append(int(input(f"Introduzca la edad de la persona {i+1}: ")))

ObjProm = Problema2(edades)
print(ObjProm.promedio())
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la lista de edades a la clase

```
edades=[]
ObjProm=Problema2()

total_personas = int(input("[!] Ingrese la c antidad de personas: "))

for i in range(total_personas):
    edades.append(int(input(f"Introduzca la edad de la persona {i+1}: ")))
    
#asigna las edades a la clase    
ObjProm._asignar(edades)

print(ObjProm.promedio())
```

Comment: Buen día, por convensión ([PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)) los métodos que inician con `_` son para uso interno. La solución es correcta pero el método debería ir sin `_` al inicio.